# Tracking if the URL in the SMS has been read by the user

Tags: php, sms, tracking

SMS are sent out to customers with a URL. 
Tracking required to see who has the Page.

How we do it
On the page we pass special unique code like page.php?unique_code=x24q23
The same code is saved in the database. 
When the page opens we match the unique code with the code in nour database. 
If the code matches we can mark the SMS link as read.

Problem. 
We use Google URL Shortner to make URL Shorter. 
Google opens the URL (probably to check and programmatically).
This marks into the database which is a false action to our logic.

Possible Problem. 
Some services possible can open URL to pickup a Screenshot or Summary to show a kind of preview to the user. This could also trigger a false action, but I am not sure.

Possible Solution.
Create a page in PHP with image headers and then loading it as image like

```
<img src="mockimage.php" />
```

Now we can read any 1px image into that file so that it works well. 
But since it is a php page we can do our logging. 
The Idea is that programmatically URL Shortner may not try to load the images. 
But when user opens the page the browser will load the page.

Question. 
What is the best suggested technique to track if the user has opened a SMS.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the user-agent : url shortener have a specific user-agent (and most of the preview bot have one too, like Slack, Bit.ly, ...).

For Google a list is here : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en (hint : you'll have to check for Googlebot).

Comment: Thanks Bacteries for helping out. 

I tired to check user-agent but unfortunately there was nothing special we could Identify to know if the result is coming from goo.gl URL Shortener. 

I am working on an old app and found that Google has ended support for their goo.gl URL shortener. 
And now promote the new URL shortener. 
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/url-shortener

We are planning to now upgrade to the new firebase URL Shortener.  
again, Thanks for helping.